# Outlook 2016 problems

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook-2016

My company “upgraded” my laptop from Windows 7 to 10. My MS Outlook 2016 is behaving very strange. First, subfolders of the inbox won’t appear until I create a “test” folder in the inbox. Then I have to do this for each subfolder. I also noticed an intermittent problem with attaching files from the toolbar (nothing happens), and my signature doesn't appear in a new email, even when I try to insert it from the toolbar (nothing happens). These problems all disappear when I run Outlook in Safe Mode, and all of the subfolders show up in OWA. Our IT department thought they fixed it, but the problems reappear intermittently depending on what I do.

What I have tried so far:

- Uninstall Office and reinstall
- Remove email profile and create a new one
- Run command > outlook.exe / resetnavpane
- Run command > outlook.exe / cleanviews

Thanks in advance for any ideas or suggestions.

Comment: If it runs in safe mode then the next step is to eliminate add-one until you discover which one is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Appleoddity, the first step is to disable all your add-ins to determine whether the issue is caused by a problematic add-in.

If issue still continues when all add-ins are disabled, then you can try renaming the following \Outlook registry key to \Outlook-1 when Outlook is closed:

Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook

Then, start Outlook and create your new profile to test it. When you start Outlook in safe mode, most of the customization settings are disabled, and these customization settings are stored in the \Outlook registry key. If it doesn't work, you can just renaming the newly generated \Outlook key to \Outlook-2, and then rename the \Outlook-1 key back to \Outlook.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Unfortunately, I can’t disable the addons, since this is a corporate laptop. FWIW- the addons are the same as they were when I had Windows 7. I tried the registry edit, and it seemed to work! And then I restarted Outlook... same problems.

Comment: >>the addons are the same as they were when I had Windows 7>> It could be add-on compatibility issue in the new Windows system. What does "can't disable the addons" refer to? Is it not allowed by the policy or something else? You can go to Outlook Files > Options > Add-ins and see whether you can disable the addons.